# PHP fgetcsv function not processing CSV properly

Tags: php, csv

Upon uploading a CSV file through `POST` to my PHP script, I want to cycle through each record on the CSV file.

This current code is infinitely looping, even though the CSV I'm submitting has fields seperated by `,` and new rows seperated by a new line.

```
while(($line = fgetcsv($file,0,',','\n')) !== FALSE) {
  echo $line[0].'<br>';
}
```

Example CSV file:

```
sampleusername,sample@email.com
anotherusername,someone@else.com
```

Comment: `'\n'` won't become a newline in single quotes.

Comment: Isn't the fourth param the enclosure char? Is it really meant to be \n?

Comment: remove \n and just put '' and try

Comment: @mario Tried double quotes, still infinitely looped.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Also tried this to no success

Comment: Please check example of this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp. try it and tell us is it working or not?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh http://pastie.org/private/f1zxyrhos5ypmgv0zwana Using this exact code, it still infinitely loops

Comment: don't show me link try to hit the examples.

Comment: I did try to "hit the examples" - they didn't work.

Comment: What is your PHP version and the operating system? When you read the temporary upload file line-by-line with fgets do you get an infinite loop as well over this two-line text-file? And as @mario has commented, the *enclosure* parameter must be a single character. And using a newline for *enclosure* (if that was your intention) probably won't work as the newline character separates records from each other.

Comment: Also please make a copy of the file that fails. Then try without upload. Can you reproduce with the uploaded file when *not* uploaded?

Comment: FYI, you're always better off using `PHP_EOL` instead of something like `\n` or `\r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using `fgetcsv()` with the only required argument, the resource - and that worked!

```
$file = fopen($_FILES['element_name']['tmp_name'], 'r');

while($line = fgetcsv($file)) {
   echo $line[0].'<br>';
}
```

Prints:

```
sample@email.com
demo@test.com
an_email@address.com
```

Answer (score -2):

The second argument is the maximum length of line, set this argument to greater than 0 (example: 1000)

Comment: "Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.1.0 and later) the maximum line length is not limited, which is slightly slower." From PHP documentation.